Problem getting Forecasts Ariba REST API - Organisation does not have the required entitlement
I'm working on a customer interface with the Ariba REST-API.
I'm able to generate the OAuth Token and getting all information from the purchaseorder and purchaseorderitems but trying to get the forecasts, needed for my customer, delivers an error with code 500 and the message

Your organisation does not have the required entitlement for this Planning OpenAPI.

I contacted the customer admin which tried to get a solution opening Ariba tickets, but the support from Ariba just closes the tickets or describes how to enable a REST API like we did for the purchaseorder.
The customer admin checked all configurations in Ariba and has no solution for the problem, the Ariba Support can't help and now i hope someone else had the same problem.
We use an admin user, the API is activated and all other API functions work, but the forecasts always deliver this error message.
I would appreciate any advice to get a solution.
I contacted the customer admin to check the Ariba configuration, we switched to an admin user for the API, and we opened three tickets in Ariba but always got the same advice which doesn't help.
